# Sinch - use Rented Long Number for Outbound

Tags: sinch

I recently rented a Long number from Sinch. Is is possible to use it to send outbound SMS

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, Set the from parameter in the request.

```
{
from:'number',
message:'my message'

}
```